# Not able to add External Data User Authentications to user profile/setting

Tags: apex, externalobjects

I am trying to add External Data User Authentications to my user in salesforce. But it's showing Named Credentilas box has my option to select but somehow it is greyed out.

Steps->Authentication Settings for External Systems->Create name-> External Defination ( Named Credential) But it is greyed out and I am not able select Anypoint named credential

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's relevant, but I faced the exact issue recently and found out that the uniquely identifying field on our user record (Field: **Federation ID** in my case) is missing. This unique field value is being used within Named Credential record for the field: **Per User Subject**

According to the Salesforce help documentation:

Per User Subject

> Per User identity type only. Formula string calculating the JWT’s subject. Include API names and constant strings in quotes. Allows a dynamic subject unique per user requesting the token. For example, 'User='+$User.Id.

After we've update the user record with a respective Federation ID, and when the user made a callout via API that uses the underlying Named Credentials, it automatically assigned a token. I hope this approach would solve your issue.

References:

1. [Define a Named Credential](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.named_credentials_define.htm&type=5)
2. [Named Credentials as Callout Endpoints](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm)